# How to find today's date in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

```
body > div.datepicker.datepicker-dropdown.dropdown-menu.datepicker-orient-left.datepicker-orient-bottom > div.datepicker-days > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td.day.today​
```

[image]

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: You should find an try different solutions and let us know what have you tried and what error you have.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'m/d/Y',
    formatDate:'m/d/Y',
    minDate:0,
    readOnly: true,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
         var dt = new Date(selected); // selected datetime
                  or
         var dt = new Date();  // current datetime
         dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
     }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
              $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
          }
        });
```